# Apns test with ad hoc provisioning

Tags: apple-push-notifications, production, provisioning-profile

I'm developing an App that works with Apple push notifications but I have some problems testing.
I have tested the app in the sandbox and it all works fine: it can send and receive push notifications, but for one single device  (I think that is the correct behavior for an sandbox release).

But when I have create an ad hoc version with his production provisioning I have the same behavior: only one device works fine, it sends and receives the push, but the others devices do not receive any push. All devices can send a push but only the the first one can receive.

After installing 'PersistentConnectionLogging.mobileconfig' on devices that can't receive a push, I can read on the console:

```
Sep  7 13:17:51 unknown apsd[49] <Warning>: <APSCourier: 0x25a0a0>: Received message for enabled topic 'myapp.name' with payload '(null)'
Sep  7 13:17:51 unknown apsd[49] <Warning>: <APSCourier: 0x25a0a0>: Failed to parse JSON message payload for topic 'myapp.name': The operation couldn’-t -b-e -c-o-m-p-l-e-t-e-d-. -(-C-o-c-o-a -e-r-r-o-r -3-8-4-0-.-)
```

I can't resolve the issue, I have regenerated the provisioning profile many times and all work fine on server sides connections, the Apple feedback is OK.

I have checked my stored devices token and sandbox and production are different, any suggestions?

Comment: How/where are you storing your device tokens? How are you generating the message to be pushed?

Comment: hi, i try to answer your question...I store my devices token on my server side, what you mean with your second question? i create my messages on my app and store it on the server for sending. The message have the same format for all devices.

Comment: Your code that connects to the push servers and creates the payload... how is it sending to >1 devices?

Comment: I use easyApns php and I am sending 1 message to a single device for time. Have you idea why a payload can be null?

Comment: I don't know the easyApns code, but either your other device tokens are invalid or the code is not looping correctly to push the message to the other devices. Also, have a browse through Google for the cocoa error 3840 and see if anything helps you to better understand the issue. Else pick some different push code, have a look at http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12 as a starting point.

Comment: you are right seems us or some problem with the format of the message. But I don't understand why all work fine, sending and receiving, on one single device... do see somtehing wrong in this message?: {"aps": {"alert": { "loc-key": "app_off","loc-args": ["senzanome","+39","3472148987","Appname","from me2","(null)"]},"badge": 1, "sound":"Appname.wav"}"acme": "APPNAME"}

Comment: You could submit and select your solution as an answer, to keep it from appearing in the unanswered questions list...

Comment: @Luke could also add an answer, which incal could then accept.

Comment: @incal if you would accept my answer, that would be most appreciated :) (tick the empty check mark and it'll go green)

Answer (score 1):

Amalgamation of comments posted as an answer, on request: (these helped to break the problem down and identify where the error was occuring)

- How/where are you storing your device tokens? How are you generating the message to be pushed?
- Your code that connects to the push servers and creates the payload... how is it sending to >1 devices?
- I don't know the easyApns code, but either your other device tokens are invalid or the code is not looping correctly to push the message to the other devices. Also, have a browse through Google for the cocoa error 3840 and see if anything helps you to better understand the issue. Else pick some different push code, have a look at [link below] as a starting point.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12